# TypeScript - howto express array of member names (keys) for a type

Tags: typescript

How can I create an expression that contains an array of member names of that given type?

Example:

```js
export type FileInfo  = {
    id: number
    title ?: string
    ext?: string|null
}
const fileinfo_fields = ["id","ext","title"];
```

I need to pass the field names to various methods for many different types.

Example:

```js
const info = await api.get_info<FileInfo>(1234, fileinfo_fields);
```

I need this because there are too many types with too many fields, and I'm affraid of making mistakes.

I understand that type information is not available at runtime, but all I need is a constant array that contains the field names.

Something like this, just I can't figure out:

```js
const fileinfo_fields = magic_extract_expression<FileInfo>; // ????
```

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Those "field names" are called `keys`. Each object has a set of "key-value" pairs. You can read out the keys of a type with TypeScript using the `keyof` operator.

For example:

```js
type FileInfo = {
    id: number
    title?: string
    ext?: string|null
}

let key: keyof FileInfo; // "id" | "title" | "ext";
```

If you want an array of keys you can do the following:

```js
const keys: (keyof FileInfo)[] = ["id", "title", "ext"];
```

You can read more on the `keyof` operator here in the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html):

Comment: The question was about finding a way to avoid typing in the keys multiple times. I know that I can re-type the names into a constant array. I'm already doing it.

Comment: I understand that the keyof in the declaration prevents from mistyping. But it does not prevent me from forgetting to add a key...